# Test should login for every spec

Tags: protractor

I am fairly new to protractor and still working to get up to the speed. 
I currently experience a weird behaviour with my protractor tests. 
I have a login test and a logout test. 
Login test works fine. But the logout test fails because it is shown the login screen first i.e , irrespective of the test I always have to login. 
I am unable to overcome this. Appreciate your suggestions. 
Attaching my protractor config file and my test spec.

```
exports.config = {
  specs: [
    './src/**/login.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  multiCapabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    os: 'Windows',
    os_version: '10',
    build_number: 'local',
    maxInstances: 2
  }],
  SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
  directConnect: false,
  connectionRetryCount: 3,
  connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: _.noop
  },
  onPrepare: () => {
    tsNode.register({
      project: path.join(__dirname, './tsconfig.e2e.json')
    });
    let reporter = new SpecReporter();
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
  }
};
```

test.spec.ts

```
import { $, browser } from 'protractor';
import { protractor } from 'protractor/built/ptor';

describe('Login page', () => {
  let EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

  it('should allow the  test user to login', async () => {
    await $('input[name=email]').sendKeys('abc@xyz.com');
    await $('input[name=password]').sendKeys('pwd');
    await $('button.auth0-lock-submit').click();
    await browser.wait(EC.titleContains('user'), 15000);
  });

  it('should allow the test user to logout', async () => {
    await $('logoutbutton').click();
    await browser.wait(EC.titleContains('loginpage'), 15000);
  });
});
```

When I execute the above test , login test passes. But the logout requires the test user to login again. Am not sure why ?

Comment: can you show how your spec file looks? to test a logout of course you have to log in first...

Comment: I have now added the test.spec.ts file

Comment: The problem is that the browser resets and launches a clean instance for every `it` block, so in order to test a logout, you need to be logged in first. You should add a log in to the second `it` before attempting to log out. Or maybe make both log in and log out to happen in the same test. Additionally, you could add a `beforeEach` function and put the log-in code there, so it logs in before every `it` block